# C protobuf-like framework, without malloc

Tags: c, protocol, serialization, code-generation

Is there a Protocol Buffers implementation, or alternative, for C99, which works with statically allocated data, without the need for `malloc`?

I.e. if all my structs have fixed length arrays:

```
// this could be autogenerated using a tool, like in protobuf

struct some_struct {

    size_t names_len;
    int names[MAX_NAMES_LEN];

    size_t addresses_len;
    int addresses[MAX_ADDRESSES_LEN];
};
```

Is there a library/framework for C which would allow serialization of such structures, without the need to write extra code?

(needless to say, it's a project with many such structs, and we would like to avoid writing serializers by hand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nanopb is a small code-size Protocol Buffers implementation in ansi C. It is especially suitable for use in microcontrollers, but fits any memory restricted system.

https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb

It lacks some of the original protocol buffers specifications such as services so it's not suitable to run RPC with it